# How do you get data from the Police API and display it on my Google Map?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, jquery, spring-mvc

I am new to handling JSON data and I am trying to learn it by getting data from the [Police API](http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/docs/) and displaying it on my Google Map.

Basically I want to take in a user input which gets Geocoded and then does a request to "http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592" (lat and long being the geocoded address).

I have been searching all over, but anything that seems to use cURL (which is what they suggest on their website), gets involved with PHP. There was a good example on richardalan.co.uk, but I have never used PHP in my life and the technologies I am using are Spring MVC, Google App Engine, Google Maps(JavaScript).

I just want to know if I can do it in my JavaScript that has also been used to create functions for my maps and how do I do it?

Thank you in advanced,

Mark

**I have now provided this question with a solution**

Comment: I think maybe I need to change the MIME type to application/json... Though I thought that is what the RestTemplate is meant to achieve, but since I have gotten my data already, is the RestTemplate really necessary?

Comment: Up to "EDIT2" now mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this now using my Spring MVC controllers to GET the JSON data I needed and then displayed it in my page and on a Google Map using JQuery AJAX.

Here is my Controller that gets the JSON data from the Police API:

```
    @Controller
public class CrimeRESTController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/crimes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object jsonCrimes(){

            SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory s = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
                super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);

                //Basic Authentication for Police API
                String authorisation = "username" + ":" + "password";
                byte[] encodedAuthorisation = Base64.encode(authorisation.getBytes());
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encodedAuthorisation));
            }
        };


        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(s);


        Object crime;
        crime = rt.getForObject("http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=53.4107766&lng=-2.9778383", Object.class);

        return crime;

    }
}
```

Here is part of my index.jsp page where I display the JSON data onto the map:

```
    <script>                
           <%---------------------------------------------------%>
           <%---------CODE THE LAT LONG IN INPUT FIELD----------%>
           <%---------------------------------------------------%>
           function codeLatLng(latitude, longitude){

               var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             position: latlng,
                             map: map
                         });
           }
           <%---------------------------------------------------%>
    </script>
```

Here is part of my index.jsp page where I loop through the JSON data to display the results to my view and also get the longitude and latitude and send it to my function shown above (I understand this might look messy and there might be a better way to do it, but it works):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function displayCrimesOnMap() {
                $.getJSON("crimes.htm", function(data) {
                   $('#crimes').text('');
                   $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                       $('#crimes').append('<br>');
                       $.each(value, function(newKey, newValue){
                           if(newKey == "location"){
                               var latitude;
                                var longitude;
                               $.each(newValue, function(key2, value2){
                                if(key2 == "latitude"){

                                    latitude = value2;
                                }
                                if(key2 == "longitude"){

                                    longitude = value2;
                                }
                                if(key2 == "street"){
                                   $('#crimes').append('<p class="areatext">' + '<b>'+key2+'</b>' + '</p>');
                                      $.each(value2, function(key3, value3){
                                           $('#crimes').append('<p class="areatext">' + '<b>'+key3+'</b>' +": " + value3 + '</p>');
                                      })
                                }else{
                                    $('#crimes').append('<p class="areatext">' + '<b>'+key2+'</b>' +": " + value2 + '</p>');
                                }

                               })
                               //alert(latitude+", "+longitude);
                               codeLatLng(latitude,longitude);
                           }else{
                                $('#crimes').append('<p class="areatext">' + '<b>'+newKey+'</b>' +": " + newValue + '</p>');
                           }
                       })
                    })
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Here is part of my index.jsp page where the information gets output to a specific section in index.jsp:

```
<h1 class="areatitle">Crimes...   <input type="button" value="Get Crimes" onclick="displayCrimesOnMap()"/></h1>
                       <div id="crimes">
                       <!--Crimes Appears Here-->
                       </div>
```

I really do hope this helps someone other than me, as I found I had a hard time understanding AJAX, after I finally understood it, it was actually really easy :)

Comment: Thank you Mark. I am implementing a crime dashboard which has to make a call to this API. Thank you for the useful info!

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to use cURL to consume this web service.  You could roll these API calls into an `XMLHTTPRequest`.  However, you're likely to run into issues with cross-domain `XMLHTTPRequest`s.  In order to get around this, you *will* need to script a way for the server to make these requests on your JavaScript's behalf, or you'll need to use a pre-built cross-domain XHR tool for this, such as [flXHR](http://flxhr.flensed.com/) or [YQL](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/).  Using a tool like this handles the request for you, and will return the JSON you want.

Comment: Thanks for the resources.

I have read about YQL and it seems in their example it is JSON-P, which during my research, I'm sure I have read that Google do not support this method anymore.

Comment: No problem. If they're helpful, you should accept the answer. If not, just let me know how else I can help, or accept another answer (if one is posted) if it does a better job of answering your question.

Comment: Hi GarlicFries, I have edited my orginal post, thanks for your input, I'm sure it is helpful to others but in my case I don't think it is, since I am using Spring controllers which I didn't mention at the beginning, so it's my fault. Thanks for your interesting input :) I do have another question posted in the edit if your familiar with spring mvc :)

Comment: Well, your question is now different altogether...not much I can do for you now.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. :)

I am getting my JSON data now, I just need to pass it from my controller to my view, so when I get it done, I will update my question, to show a good answer. Might write a tutorial on this as well for anyone who may be interested.

Comment: Hi Garlic, I have now put an answer to my question in case you are interested. Thanks for your input as well, I found it very useful and It enabled me to actively find similar technologies such as Jquery-AJAX which I could then use. It seems your answer is also correct, but not in a way I could understand it at the time, having never touched technologies like this before.